# MongoDB MapReduce many emit()'s per key

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Are all `emit()`s of the same key guaranteed to be sent to a reduce function?

For example, if you had 1 million documents that `emit()` once per each document but for only 10 possible `emit()` keys (spread evenly) would the reduce function get slammed with 100k emissions in a single call?

Or would mongo split these up and progressively reduce the result? If so how does it decide how many values to send to the reduce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the emit()s for the same key will be sent to a reduce function, but they won't necessarily be send to the reduce function at once (if a single document was emitted for a particular key, the document won't be passed to the reduce function).  Reduce may be called multiple times for the same key, which is why it's important that the result of the reduce function match the structure of the documents emitted by the map function.

I'll try to find out more information about the logic behind how and when mongo splits up documents before passing them to the reduce function.

Comment: Basically it's determined by the amount of available RAM, which MR tries not to exceed. For that reason, it's beneficial to use the "sort" option so that all of the same keys arrive in memory at one time (and are reduced together).

Comment: what's the solution if we want to include key with single document in results ???